# How to fix orientation of few controller in portrait mode only?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I am developing an application in which i am having one `Navigation Controller`  which further has few `ViewController` as child.Now for few `ViewController` i want keep the orientation for portrait mode.How can i do that ?

**EDIT:**

I created custom view controller class as `PortraitViewController` & add below code in `PortraitViewController.m`

```
@interface PortraitViewController ()

@end

@implementation PortraitViewController

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{

    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    //Here check class name and then return type of orientation
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

@end
```

After that i implemented `PortraitViewController.h` as base class

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "PortraitViewController.h"
@interface Login : PortraitViewController
@end
```

But still now working if rotate the device into landscape mode.

Comment: What have you done until now ? Any Code?

Comment: yes. i have code..sharing in a minute

Answer (score 1):

Create custom class "PortraitViewController". and write this code.

```
@interface PortraitViewController ()

@end

@implementation PortraitViewController

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{

    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    //Here check class name and then return type of orientation
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

@end
```

Assign this class as baseclass for your viewcontroller and you can do same thing for UINavigationController

Comment: I am just beginner so please tell me how can i assign this as my base class for my view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Create custom NavController and add as super class to your view controller.

```
#import "PotraitNAVController.h"

@interface PotraitNAVController ()

@end

@implementation PotraitNAVController

//implement this methods in your viewcontroller also, this will tell navigation controller to allow which type of rotation is allowed.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{

    //Here check topviewcontroller and allow rotation to no if you want it in potrait
    return self.topViewController.shouldAutorotate;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return self.topViewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations;
}
@end
```

Comment: In this case all my view controller in one navigation controller in portrait mode but i have a situation where few view controller can under landscape mode & few controller under portrait mode under same navigation controller.@Ruchish